# stdout comparison to a hash result (python)

Tags: python

using python i create a hash result for a file. i retrieve a hash result from somewhere else, but i have to retrieve it using stdout, and i would like to compare the two. however the retrieved stdout is retrieved as a list, and has a `\n` at the end. if i print it it might look, for example, like this: `[6d52f\n]`

i know that the problem is that if i try to add the `\n` to my current hash result, it automatically disregards the `\n` to try to compare the two (like i do below in my code), so i'm currently a bit unsure about how i can compare the two. i know the answer is probably staring me in the face, but i would appreciate any help.

my code is:

```
if ("%s\n" % thishash == otherhash):
    print "they are the same"
else:
    print "they are not the same"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply strip the newline from the `stdin`:

```
>>> x = ['6d52f\n']
>>> x[0].rstrip('\n')
'6d52f'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to retrieve it using stdout

You might mean "stdin", not "stdout".

```
other_hash = raw_input() # no trailing newline
if this_hash == other_hash: 
   "same"
```

Or you could call `other_hash.rstrip()` without arguments to remove all trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply [strip](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip) to otherhash:

```
if thishash == otherhash.strip():
    print "they are the same"
else:
    print "they are not the same"
```

Some additional recommendations:

1. Don't use insignificant bracket. Be pythonic.
2. Probably [lowercasing](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.lower) otherhash could be a good idea.